# winforms, help needed to create a dynamic tablelayoutpanel with buttons

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, button, visual-studio-2017, dynamic-tables

I am trying to create a dynamic tablelayout which creates adds a skill and gives that skill 1 level and a increase decrease button. I am struggling with having the buttons access the level label. I thought about finding the location of the button that was clicked, but could figure out how to do that.

In advance, Thank you.

example:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ma68T.png)

this is what i have so far:

```
        private void skilladded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 1;
        int[] position= { 0,0};
        bool test = false;
        //string select;
        int k=0;
        for (i=1;i<=skillstableLayoutPanel.RowCount;i++)
        {
            Control c= skillstableLayoutPanel.GetControlFromPosition(0,i);

            if (c!=null&&addskillswin.selected==c.Text)
            {
                test = true;
                k = i;
                break;

            }
            else if(c==null)
            {
                k = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (test==false)
        {

            Label newskill = new Label();
            Label newskilllvl = new Label();
            TableLayoutPanel buttontable = new TableLayoutPanel();


            Button up = new Button();
            Button down = new Button();
            buttontable.ColumnCount = 2;
            buttontable.RowCount = 1;
            buttontable.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent,100f));
            buttontable.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent,50f));
            buttontable.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50f));
            buttontable.Margin = new Padding(0,0,0,0);
            buttontable.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            buttontable.Controls.Add(up, 0, 0);
            buttontable.Controls.Add(down, 1, 0);
            up.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.up;[enter image description here][2]
            down.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.down;
            up.BackgroundImageLayout=ImageLayout.Stretch;
            down.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
            newskill.Text = addskillswin.selected;
            newskilllvl.Text = "1";
            up.Margin = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            down.Margin = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            skillstableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(newskill,0,k);
            skillstableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(newskilllvl, 1, k);
            skillstableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(buttontable, 2, k);
            skillavaillabel.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(skillavaillabel.Text) - 1).ToString();
            skillpointlvl = Convert.ToInt32(newskilllvl.Text);

            up.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(skillup);                     
            down.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(skilldown);


        }
        if (test==true)
        {
            skillstableLayoutPanel.GetControlFromPosition(1, k).Text = (Convert.ToInt32(skillstableLayoutPanel.GetControlFromPosition(1, k).Text) + 1).ToString();
            skillavaillabel.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(skillavaillabel.Text) -1).ToString();
        }

    }
    private void skillup(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        skillpointlvl++;

    }
    private void skilldown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        skillpointlvl--;
    }
```

Comment: Are there up and down buttons for each skill that you add? If I added a new skill, Mine, to the list, would that have its own up/down buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
up.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(skillup);                     
down.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(skilldown);
```

Try something like this:

```
up.MouseClick += ((o, me) =>
{
    int currentLevel = Int32.Parse(newskilllvl.Text);
    currentLevel++;
    newskilllvl.Text = currentLevel.ToString();
});

down.MouseClick += ((o, me) =>
{
    int currentLevel = Int32.Parse(newskilllvl.Text);
    currentLevel--;
    newskilllvl.Text = currentLevel.ToString();
});
```

Your `skillup` or `skilldown` event handler could potentially process each sender and see from which button the click originated, but you'd have to uniquely name each button and do a lot of string comparisons to see which button corresponds to which skill level label. The code above adds an anonymous handler to each button, which allows us to essentially tie the button being clicked to its corresponding skill label.

Personally though, I would not store all these values in labels like you have done. I would either store them in properties on the form, or better yet in a class of their own. I would also put all this logic somewhere else beside the form, like in a Presenter or Controller (or class library), and follow a design pattern such as MVC or MVP. This will make maintaining and changing the application easier in the long run.

Also, consider using camel case and Pascal case for your variable names. All lowercase variables are harder for experienced programmers to read.

Comment: thanks for the advice. will look into turning it into a separate class or something. the naming convention is due to laziness, so my bad.